# How to setup click event in directive in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive like this

```
<div my-directive="htmlItem"></div>  //htmlItem is dynamic
```

my directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                myDirective: '='
            },
            controller: myDirectiveCtrl
        };
    }]);


function myDirectiveCtrl($scope) {
    console.log($scope.myDirective)  => output html like <div>Product</div>

    //I want to add click event in my html so it becomes
    //<div ng-click="vm.clickProduct()">Product</div>
    //I do

    angular.element($scope.myDirective).find('div').attr('ng-click',  
    'vm.clickProduct()');           
}
```

I see `vm.clickProduct()` in my html when I inspect element from browser but when I click it, click event never fire. Is there a way to trigger the `vm.clickProduct()`? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

you need to compile your html using $compile to trigger ng-click on your button.
like this
$compile(yourHTML)($scope);

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `link` function as follows:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController',function(){});
myApp.directive('htmlItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            myDirective: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind('click', function() {
            alert('you have clicked');
          })
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div html-item="">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

myDirectiveCtrl is having that click function u should mention the name as there in controller and alias name of controller too vm is defined as alias name of controller so controllerAs also required

'vm.clickProduct()->Use like clickProduct() if that template is in the Controller scope.otherwise use a function in link from there u call your Controller method